# Exception occured org.osgi.framework.BundleException while deploying custom plugin in OAM(Oracle Access Manager)

Tags: osgi, unboundid-ldap-sdk, oam

I'm developing custom plugin for OAM using unboundid-ldapsdk. I'm not able to activate this plugin in OAM as it throws below error

### This is manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-Version: 10
    Bundle-Name: CustomPlugIn
    Bundle-Activator: sample.CustomPlugIn
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-SymbolicName: CustomPlugIn
    Import-Package: oracle.security.am.plugin,oracle.security.am.plugin.authn,oracle.security.am.plugin.impl,org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",com.unboundid.ldap.sdk;version="4.0.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: .,lib/unboundid-ldapsdk.jar
```

---

Error :

```
Caused By: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle CustomPlugIn [4]: Unable to resolve 4.0: missing requirement [4.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.unboundid.ldap.sdk)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3980)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2043)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2426.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at oracle.security.am.plugin.internal.OSGIPluginService.installAndStartBundle(OSGIPluginService.java:179)
        at oracle.security.am.extensibility.lifecycle.messaging.NodeMessageListener.installAndStartBundle(NodeMessageListener.java:66)
        at oracle.security.am.extensibility.lifecycle.messaging.NodeMessageListener.receiveMessage(NodeMessageListener.java:112)
        at oracle.security.am.extensibility.lifecycle.messaging.NodeMessageListener.receiveMessageList(NodeMessageListener.java:49)
        at oracle.security.am.extensibility.lifecycle.messaging.MessageListenerWrapper.objectCreated(MessageListenerWrapper.java:30)
        at oracle.security.am.foundation.mapimpl.coherence.events.MapListenerWrapper.notifyListener(MapListenerWrapper.java:174)
        at oracle.security.am.foundation.mapimpl.coherence.events.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:132)
        at oracle.security.am.foundation.mapimpl.coherence.events.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:114)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: the error says that the package com.unboundid.ldap.sdk is missing, so that probably means that no bundle is "export" ing it. if you know what bundle should do it you have to deploy it in your OSGI container

Comment: Thanks @isco but if you go through the manifest file you will see that bundle is exported.. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: No, in the manifest we can see that the package is imported, not exported. So another bundle has to export that package